# Partial Derivatives - BWRS Equation of State

Tags: thermodynamics, gas

I require the following two partial derivatives from the [BWRS Equation of State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benedict%E2%80%93Webb%E2%80%93Rubin_equation#The_BWRS_equation_of_state) (BWR modified by Starling).

$\left (\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}  \right )_{T}$

$\left (\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}  \right )_{P}$

These are two terms which are commonly used to evaluate isothermal compressibility and volume expansivity.

If anyone could please advise how to complete this derivation it would be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the BWRS equation (where S stands for Soave, not Starling), pressure P is expressed explicitly in terms of molar density $\rho$ and temperature T as $P=P(T,\rho)$. Furthermore, the molar density is related to the molar volume in your equations by:  $$V=\frac{1}{\rho}$$Therefore, $$\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\right)_T=-\frac{1}{\rho^2}\left(\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial P}\right)_T=-\frac{1}{\rho^2}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial \rho}\right)_T}$$and
$$\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P=-\frac{1}{\rho^2}\left(\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial T}\right)_P$$
At constant P, we have $$dP=\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_{\rho}dT+\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial \rho}\right)_{T}d
\rho=0$$From this, it follows that $$\left(\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial T}\right)_P=-\frac{\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_{\rho}}{\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial \rho}\right)_{T}}$$So,$$\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P=\frac{1}{\rho^2}\frac{\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_{\rho}}{\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial \rho}\right)_{T}}$$

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, I am now getting excellent agreement with my numerically estimated value via central difference method. Just to clarify, I am using Starlings modification to the original BWR equation of state. Thanks again.